# Add an on-link route in netplan

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, netplan

I'm trying to replicate in Netplan the equivalent of

```
ip -6 r a 2605:6400:1:fed5::1 dev eth0
```

There's no "via" address. I've tried:

```
      routes:
        - to: "2605:6400:1:fed5::1"
          on-link: true
```

But unfortunately, netplan comes back with an error

```
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 13 column 8: unicast route must include both a 'to' and 'via' IP
```

Is there a fake 'via' address I should use? It seems netplan doesn't even have post-up hooks so I can't work around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions of netplan >= 0.40 you can use:

```
eth0:
  routes:
    - to: "2605:6400:1:fed5::1"
      scope: link
```

In older versions you can use the "::" catch-all:

```
eth0:
  routes:
    - to: "2605:6400:1:fed5::1"
      via: "::"
      on-link: true
```

Comment: Nope: `Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 13 column 8: unicast route must include both a 'to' and 'via' IP`

Comment: Are you sure? I don't have a real good setup for testing now, but with Ubuntu 18 and netplan it doesn't give an error and it does make a ipv6 route. With ipv4 it certainly works.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, I pasted it to routes and issued `netplan apply`. maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Do you have netplan >= 0.40? In lower versions it seems you can use via: "::"

Comment: I can confirm that: 1) via: "::" worked in 0.32 which comes out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04 and 2) upgrading to 0.96 removed the need for the 'via' directive. Want to make it an answer or should I? Thanks!